# How to create left navigation drawer when top header logo is fixed and menu item is scrolling and show in category title?

Tags: android, android-layout, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am new in android so please guide me How to create left navigation drawer when top header logo is fixed and  menu item is scrolling and show in category title exact like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4acF.png)

**I am trying this code**

**XML FIle is**

My Navigation drawer is here - [nav_header_main.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNH-Zpp1suAVDhJSmtOdmFEWk0) and

menu file is in res/menu/

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Main Category"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />

    <item android:title="Communicate">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="Share" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Send" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />

    <item android:title="App Category"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />

</menu>
```

my activity_main file is

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried.

Comment: i have edit my code please check it.

Comment: see my answer. you need to create custom navigation for this.

Comment: In custom layout add imageview on top and then scrollview and inside scrollview all your layout. so logo will be fixed and items can scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by custom drawer. Try below link. Hope it will solve your problem.

[Custom navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632492/8089770)

**In custom layout add imageview on top and then scrollview and inside scrollview all your layout. so logo will be fixed and items can scroll.**

Or you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122753/fixed-navigation-header-in-navigation-drawer-while-scrolling-through-items) solutions.